# How do I set tabindex to -1 in GWT?

Tags: gwt, tabindex

I have this problem with GWT: I need to skip a button from the focus cycle so I set the tab index to -1 with button.setTabIndex(-1), but in the generated html I get tabindex="0"... is this a bug?

Comment: That's is the way to set it. So could you post a snippet demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's on-purpose: `FocusWidget`'s `onAttach` resets the tab index to 0 in `onAttach` when it was set to -1: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.java

This behavior dates back to 3½ years ago (released in GWT 2.1.0): https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=7642 so I'm surprised you're the first to report it (that I know of), but it indeed looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is impossible to have a negative tabindex.

At first, the doc of `setTabIndex` say :

> Sets the widget's position in the tab index. If more than one widget
>   has the same tab index, each such   widget will receive focus in an
>   arbitrary order. Setting the tab index to -1 will cause this widget to
>   be   removed from the tab order.

And w3c say :

> Elements that may receive focus should be navigated by user agents
>   according to the following rules:
>
> 1. Those elements that support the tabindex attribute and assign a positive value to it are navigated first. Navigation proceeds from the
>      element with the lowest tabindex value to the element with the highest
>      value. Values need not be sequential nor must they begin with any
>      particular value. Elements that have identical tabindex values should
>      be navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.
> 2. Those elements that do not support the tabindex attribute or support it and assign it a value of "0" are navigated next. These
>      elements are navigated in the order they appear in the character
>      stream.
> 3. Elements that are disabled do not participate in the tabbing order.

Source : http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

But if you want to skipe your button, try to set the tabindex < -1.
Example :

```
Button myButton = new Button("Hello");
myButton.setTabIndex(-2);
// "-1" is convert to 0, and the button is not skipped
```

I try `myButton.setTabIndex(-1);` and `myButton.getElement.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1")`, that is always convert to 0 in html.

I wish that help you.

Comment: "It seems it is impossible to have a negative tabindex": HTML4 disallowed it but browsers had to handle the case, and [HTML5 now defines it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute); the rest of your answer is exactly the problem originally reported in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Working with jsni.
For example:

```
public static native void setElementTabIndex(Element b, int ti)/*-{
        b.tabIndex = ti;
     }-*/;

//and call the native js function
setElementTabIndex(odButton.getElement(), -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As with setFocus, use deferred:

```
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                cb.setTabIndex(-1);
            }
  });
```

Where in my case cb = CheckBox()